# Converting .db dates in OSX to readable dates using R

Tags: r, date, macos-high-sierra

I'm working on an app that organizes all of ones facebook and text messages into one searchable, analyzable, printable interface. Part a was connecting into the facebook API and that was easy. Part two is connecting to the chat.db SQLite database in OSX... everything is there in R, but I'm having trouble converting the chat.db dates into a readable format.

Here is what I have coded so far:

```
    setwd('/Users/****/Library/Messages')
    require(RSQLite)

    filename <- "chat.db"
    sqlite.driver <- dbDriver("SQLite")
    db <- dbConnect(sqlite.driver,
            dbname = filename)
## Some operations
dbListTables(db)
message <- dbReadTable(db,"message")
handle <- dbReadTable(db,"handle")

chat <- subset(message, message$handle_id == 40 | message$handle_id == 8)
colnames <- c('text', 'date' , 'is_from_me')
chat <- chat[colnames]
for (i in 1:nrow(chat)){
  if (chat$is_from_me[i] == 1)
    {chat$sender[i] <- 'Sent'}
  else if  (chat$is_from_me[i] == 0)
    {chat$sender[i] <- 'Received'}
}
chat$type <- "Text Message"
colnames <- c('is_from_me')
chat <- chat[-3]
```

First thing I tried was the exact same thing I tried  with the facebook API. It worked with that API with a converted JSON file, but I haven't had the same luck with the .db file:

```
test <- as.POSIXct(chat$date/1000, origin = '1970-01-01' )
```

I'm not sure of the origin in the .db files, but I was just going to run the above code to see if the result makes sense... it doesn't

Comment: https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/issues/237 ?

Comment: Part a and part 2? ;)

Comment: What format does the date come out in right now? There might be another lib you can use to parse the date into something uniform

Comment: I have to write them to characters. I tried this and it worked in R:


        chat$date <-as.POSIXct(chat$date/1000000000, origin = '2001-01-01', tz = "UTC-6" )

However, pushing that to .csv and tableau, the string reads in as military time, but also puts an "AM" or "PM" at the end, which makes things a little funny.